# Can't achieve smooth transition between react router pages with Framer Motion

Tags: css, css-animations, web-frontend, framer-motion, react-animations

It is been over a week now, and I can't get it to work!, I am trying to make a transition between react pages components to have it scroll up and down for each page.however, on exit page the second page takes longer to be displayed and I can't figure out how to sync it so while the first page goes up, the second page start to goes up as well at the same time.

I am using **AnimatePresence** with **exitBeforeEnter** wrapping the app component.
Appreciate any help to the right directions.

Below are my variants for each component

```
const containerVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: "-100vh",
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    y: 0,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 15,
      damping: 10,
      mass: 0.4,
      staggerChildern: 0.4,
      // opacity: { duration: 0.02 },
      when: "beforeChildren",
    },
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
    y: "-100vh",
    zIndex: 0,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 15,
      opacity: { duration: 3 },
    },
  },
};

const Home = () => {
 
  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={containerVariants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
      exit="exit"
    >
< code goes here>
    </motion.div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might already have it, but did you add the `key`s to pages inside `<AnimatePresence`? In my experience forgetting them caused issues with animating between pages/components.

Another issue I encountered was because of the `key` not being set on the immediate child of `<AnimatePresence>` (I had layout components between AnimatePresence and the pages).

Maybe you already have this all setup correctly, just to be sure :)

In my current project:

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  <Component
    {...pageProps}
    key={router.route}
    err={err}
  />
</AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: Hi Wiljan Thank you for your reply. I had added key in switch complement       `<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.key}>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route extact path="/aboutme">
            <AboutMe />
          </Route>
          <Route extact path="/projects">
            <Projects />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </AnimatePresence>` would that make any difference?

Comment: @JohnYacoub I'm not completely sure how React-Router's Switch works internally, I'm currently using Next.JS. I've found this example using `<Switch>` inside `<AnimatePresence>`: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-x-react-router-n7qhp?file=/src/index.js

Maybe that helps? The only difference I see at first glance is that the used key is location.pathname instead of your location.key, although I doubt that would make any difference.

Comment: Hi wiljan!thank you for the code snippet , I tried but I didn't make any difference as the key is just identifier to let AnimatePresence know which component is being used.

Comment: You have to specify the key prop as "key={location.pathname}" in the <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>